# How can I get all active sessions in a jax-rs application?

Tags: java, session, servlets, jax-rs

I know how to get the caller Session, I inject the servlet request and get the Session object from it, but I don't know how to get the other callers sessions.

```
@Context
HttpServletRequest request;

...

Session session = request.getSession();
// Session[] a = request.getAllSessions(); // this would be great
```

Comment: API does not provide you with such a feature. Why do you need it? Maybe there is another way to achieve it.

Comment: is an existing project, they save user data and permissions as a Session attribute, I need to change the permissions of a given user at runtime

Comment: Can you modify the behaviour a bit? If you had a global - session scoped bean - that gets notified when user permissions change, then you could just put a reference to such bean (that would cache roles, permissions etc.) into the session object and use it to verify permissions with every request.